# Find two primitive pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a$ odd, $b$ even and $c=a+2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Find two primitive Pythagorean triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a$ odd and $b$ even, such that $c=a+2$.

I know the  Conditions for primitive triples are: $ a^2 + b^2 = c^2, \quad (a,b) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define new integer variables $x,y$ such that

$a = 2y+1$  and $b = 2x$

Since $c = a+2$ then $c = 2y+3$ and substituting these into the Pythagorean identity we have

$(2y + 1)^{2} + (2x)^{2} = (2y + 3)^{2} $

we can expand the brackets

$4y^{2}+4y+1 + 4x^{2} = 4y^{2}+12y+9$

cancel like terms and rearrange

$ x^{2} = 2y+2$

This tells us that any even x^2 greater than 2 will give a valid y from which we can find a corresponding Pythagorean triple. (even because $2y+2$ is even and odd x will yield odd x^{2})

x | y | (a,b,c)

---

2 | 1 | (3,4,5)

4 | 7 | (15,8,17)

6 | 17| (35,12,37)

8 | 31| (63,16,65)

etc...

Answer (score 3):

How about $a=3$, $b=4$, $c=5$?

Edit: Sorry, thought you just needed one. Since $c = a+2$, you can write
$$ a^2 + b^2 = (a+2)^2$$
which simplifies to 
$$ b^2 = 4(a+1) $$
Thus pick $a := x^2 - 1$ for some $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x \geq 2$. This gives you $b = 2x$ and $c = x^2 + 1$.

$x=2$ gives $(3,4,5)$

$x=3$ yields $(6,8,10)$ which is not primitive, but $x=4$ works, giving $(15,8,17)$.

Comment: I think "find two" is another way of saying "find one that isn't $(3, 4, 5)$".

Comment: not understand anything ,give more explanation please

Comment: @user155971 Added explanation, is that more helpful

Answer (score 0):

These functions generate only and all primitive triples where $C=A+2$
$$A=4n^2-1\qquad B=4n\qquad C=4n^2+1$$

Here are the triples for $1\le n \le 25$
$$(3,4,5)\quad (15,8,17)\quad (35,12,37)\quad (63,16,65)\quad (99,20,101)\quad (143,24,145)\quad (195,28,197)\quad (255,32,257)\quad (323,36,325)\quad (399,40,401)\quad (483,44,485)\quad (575,48,577)\quad (675,52,677)\quad (783,56,785)\quad (899,60,901)\quad (1023,64,1025)\quad (1155,68,1157)\quad (1295,72,1297)\quad (1443,76,1445)\quad (1599,80,1601)\quad (1763,84,1765)\quad (1935,88,1937)\quad (2115,92,2117)\quad (2303,96,2305)\quad (2499,100,2501)$$

Answer (score -2):

A simple google search yields multiple results:

a= 99, b = 20, c = 101